# Proper way to set up Rails app on local machine using existing Github repo and RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, rvm, repository

I've tried looking around the internet for a solution to this but to no avail. Every single time I try to set up a new app on my local machine I run into a ridiculous amount of issues with RVM. I decided its finally time I learn to do this right.

Basically I have been given permission to a Rails project in Github and I want to get it running properly on my local machine.

Generally speaking, what I have been doing in the past is this:

```
$ git clone git@github.com/projectpath
$ ls projectpath
$ bundle install 
$ rake db:setup
```

And cross my fingers. Sometimes it works, other times I have to use RVM to change rubies and redo bundle install. Today, everything is breaking and I keep running into problems like this:

```
$ rails -v
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

I have a feeling that I am not setting up these apps correctly and also not using RVM as its supposed to be used - basically I believe that my fundamental understanding of RVM is wrong. I would very greatly appreciate it if someone could outline the proper way to do set up a new app using a remote Github repo, as well as explain the proper way to use RVM to get this new app running. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your life would be easier if you used RVM's gemsets.  One gemset per rails application.  This keeps everything nice and isolated from each other.

So... something like this...

```
# install bundler in the global gemset as you want it available everywhere.
$ rvm use @global
$ gem install bundler

# create a project specific rvmrc/gemset.
$ cd /folder/containing/your/github/repo
$ echo "rvm use @myapp" > .rvmrc
$ cd into/rails/root/for/your/app
$ bundle install
```

At this point you're installing the gems into the 'myapp' gemset, totally isolated from your other gems.  There's a new file name for .rvmrc, but I can never remember what it is. .ruby-version or something.

You may also need to create the gemset before it can be used.  See the RVM docs for how to make that happen automatically.

Comment: This helped me, the gem organization makes much more sense now. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Do these cloned projects have files named
.ruby-version
and
.ruby-gemset
in the top level directory? Those files instruct rvm (and other versioning systems) to use a particular ruby version and gemset combo. It could be sometimes you cd into a cloned directory that references the name of a gemset you've already created, in which case bundle and rake work, and sometimes it references a gemset you don't have, in which case you get mysterious blowups.

Comment: Something along these lines was definitely going on. Started the app from scratch, and created a new gemset for the app. Works great now. Thanks